# HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED in C

Tags: c, heap-memory, corruption

I am having some problems with my program and getting this error :
HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: before Normal block (#9873672) at 0x00968988.
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory before start of heap buffer.

I have tried to look for fixes but I can't figure out what it wrong with my program, what to fix and where :(
Here is the function I'm using and that is causing me problems :
What I am doing is basically look into a file for a specific keyword (argument of the function getText) and printing its matching value.
Sorry if most of the variables are in French, it's a project for school and our teacher require us to use French names >_<

```
#include "getText.h"
#include "main.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

texteLangue* ressourcesTexteLangue = NULL;
int compteur = 0;


char* getText(char* clef)
{
    char* texte = NULL;
    texte = clef; //clef is the keyword passed in the function as argument
    texteLangue temp;
    temp.clef = clef;
    texteLangue* resultat = (texteLangue*) bsearch(&temp, ressourcesTexteLangue, compteur, sizeof(texteLangue), comparerClef); //returns the value associated with the key

    if (clef != NULL)
    {
            if (resultat != NULL)
            texte = resultat->valeur;
    }
    return texte; 
}

void lectureTexte(char* langue)
{
    char nomFichierRessources[64];
    sprintf(nomFichierRessources, "ressources_%s.txt", langue); //give the file name a specific ending depending on the language chosen
    FILE* FichierRessources = fopen(nomFichierRessources, "r");
    if (FichierRessources == NULL)
    {
        system("cls");
        perror("The following error occured ");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(42);
    }

        //allocates memory for the language resources 
    int taille = 10;
    ressourcesTexteLangue = (texteLangue *) calloc(taille, sizeof(texteLangue));
    if (ressourcesTexteLangue == NULL)
        printf("Pas assez de place mémoire pour les ressources texte");


        //gives a value to TextResource.key and TextResource.value for each line of the file
    char* ligne;
    while ((ligne = lectureLigne(FichierRessources)))
    {
        if (strlen(ligne) > 0)
        {
            if (compteur == taille)
            {
                taille += 10;
                ressourcesTexteLangue = (texteLangue *) realloc(ressourcesTexteLangue, taille * sizeof(texteLangue));
            }
            ressourcesTexteLangue[compteur].clef = ligne;

            while (*ligne != '=')
            {
                ligne++;
            }

            *ligne = '\0';
            ligne++;
            ressourcesTexteLangue[compteur].valeur = ligne;
            compteur++;
        }
     }
         //sorts out the values of TextResource obtained
     qsort(ressourcesTexteLangue, compteur, sizeof(texteLangue), comparerClef);

     fclose(FichierRessources);
}

 //reads a line and returns it
 char* lectureLigne(FILE *fichier)
 {
    int longeur = 10, i = 0, c = 0;
    char* ligne = (char*) calloc(longeur, sizeof(char));

    if (fichier)
    {
        c = fgetc(fichier);
        while (c != EOF)
        {
            if (i == longeur)
            {
                longeur += 10;
                ligne = (char*) realloc(ligne, longeur * sizeof(char));
            }
            ligne[i++] = c;
            c = fgetc(fichier);
            if ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r'))
                break;
        }

        ligne[i] = '\0';

        while ((c == '\n') || (c == '\r'))
            c = fgetc(fichier);
        if (c != EOF)
            ungetc(c,fichier);

        if ((strlen(ligne) == 0) && (c == EOF))
        {
            free(ligne);
            ligne = NULL;
        }
    }
    return ligne;
}

//frees the TextRessources
void libererTexte()
{
    if (ressourcesTexteLangue != NULL)
    {
        while (compteur--)
        {
            free(ressourcesTexteLangue[compteur].clef);

        }
        free(ressourcesTexteLangue);
    }
}

//compares the keys
int comparerClef(const void* e1, const void* e2)
{
    return strcmp(((texteLangue*) e1)->clef, ((texteLangue*) e2)->clef);
}
```

the structure of RessourceTextelangue (TextResources) look like this :

```
typedef struct texteLangue {
    char* clef;
    char* valeur;
} texteLangue;
```

Comment: That is a typical error when you write outside of dynamic allocated memory.

Comment: You might want to step though the code in a debugger, line by line, with a simple example data file. If you do this while checking indexes into the different arrays and strings you might find it out.

Comment: Don't do stuff like this: `ligne = (char*) realloc(ligne, longeur * sizeof(char));` If realloc fails you've lost the pointer to the original block of memory resulting in a possible leak.

Comment: If you run it through valgrind it will tell you exactly where you made the error, to the line, then it should be much easier to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Is your input guaranteed to contain a '=' in each line?

```
while (*ligne != '=') // if not, this will fly off the end of your buffer...
{
    ligne++;
}

*ligne = '\0'; // ...and write to unallocated heap memory
```

*Edit*

Given @Heath's comment, if your input contains a blank line (including ending with a single blank line) then the above would most certainly be triggered.

```
c = fgetc(fichier); // reads '\n'
while (c != EOF)
{
    ...

    ligne[i++] = c;

    ...

    ligne[i] = '\0';
```

`ligne` now contains "\n" and is returned. later it is used:

```
if (strlen(ligne) > 0) // strlen("\n") is greater than 0
{
    ...

    while (*ligne != '=') // oops! loop until we find a '=' somewhere
                          // in the heap or crash trying.
    {
        ligne++;
    }

    *ligne = '\0'; // corrupt the heap here
```

Comment: Yes, there is always a '=' on each line !

Comment: @Zoe -- Nevertheless, you should correct this code for the event that someday, there isn't.  Also, are you 100% sure your file does not end with a "blank" line containing only "\n"?

Answer (score 1):

There are several potential problems with your code that could be causing the error report you see.

Here is one:

```
    if (i == longeur)
```

should be:

```
    if ((i+1) == longeur)
```

otherwise,

```
    ligne[i] = '\0';
```

can occur in conditions when

```
        ligne[i++] = c;
```

has caused `i` to become equal to `longeur`.

Here is another:

```
        while (*ligne != '=')
        {
            ligne++;
        }

        *ligne = '\0';
```

the above code should be:

```
        while (*ligne != '=' && *ligne != '\0')
        {
            ligne++;
        }

        *ligne = '\0';
```

otherwise, you will corrupt memory in the case when there is no `'='` to be found in the string.

Although either of these could cause the symptom you report, I see some other oddities that make me think there is more wrong than I have seen so far.  Nevertheless, fixing those two problems will at least reduce the number of possibilities you have to consider.

Comment: I have fixed those problems but I am still getting the error :/

Comment: You could post your entire program and test input somewhere.  Or the suggestion elsewhere to use valgrind is a good one.